# ¿Qué versión del adaptador se está instanciando al registrar?

Tags: phalcon

Tengo una duda respecto a la autocarga. Necesito usar el adaptador de MongoDB que viene dentro de Incubator y estoy viendo que en la documentación pone que se debe registrar el nombre de espacio Phalcon:

```php
<?php
$loader->registerNamespaces([
        'Phalcon' => '/path/to/incubator/Library/Phalcon/',
]);
```

La duda que tengo es: si registro este nombre de espacio, que es el que viene por defecto en el framework, ¿cuando instancie Phalcon\Http\Request me instancia desde incubator o del Framework?

Lo pregunto porque he visto que dentro de git incubator hay carpetas para casi todos los componentes que Phalcon ya tiene integrados, como por ejemplo: Request, Response, Mvc, etc

Comment: Hola @Infobuscador, es importante que las preguntas tengan títulos descriptivos que ayuden a identificarlas. He cambiado el título, por favor comprueba que se ajusta bien a lo que buscas. Y completa el [tour] para más información (y con ello ganarás una nueva medalla). Saludos.